# Tomcat, mod_cluster, and Amazon EC2?

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, cloud, cluster-computing

I recently came across [this article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tomcat%20dynamic%20cluster%20mod_cluster%20&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48086&ei=KbbQT9ziHufY0QH3huTTDQ&usg=AFQjCNHPT7MV6Pm3plvDy_1yqQ4smxqG1A&sig2=iiUkr1Sp1Qjl3n399IVRdw), discussing how to leverage mod_cluster to create dynamic Tomcat clusters.  My company is about to take our first leap into Amazon's EC2 cloud, and will be deploying our application on Tomcat 7.  We'd like to take advantage of mod_cluster so that we can dynamically scale our application as traffic increases.  EC2, however, does not support the use of multicast, which is how this document has you configure your cluster setup.

Has anyone setup mod_cluster for dynamic Tomcat clusters in the EC2 environment?  I saw a small mention of leveraging S3 for storing information about the cluster members, but couldn't find any documentation explaining how to do it.  Has anyone seen any good docs or tutorials on the subject?  Personal experience?  I'd appreciate any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using of jbossas 7. I Think is easier to configure and more suitable for clustering, especially in the cloud.

And you can use mod_cluster ;)

Here the cluster tutorial: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/AS7+Cluster+Howto

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with Mod_cluster in Amazon's EC2 cloud provided you use proxy-list configuration.

Multicast is used for httpd balancer to advertise itself. New worker nodes can pick this up and register themselves with the balancer.
Zero configuration.

With no multicast available, advertising is off. What you have to do is to tell the workers where to look for the balancer. Httpd balancer's configuration, unlike with mod_jk, needs no modification (you don't specify anything about any worker).

For Tomcat6:

```
<Listener className="org.jboss.modcluster.container.catalina.standalone.ModClusterListener"
  proxyList="mybalacer.com:port" ...
  ...
/>
```

For AS7:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
  <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" proxy-list="mybalacer.com:port" ...
  ...
  </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever used mod_cluster, but you might want to look into Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk since your implementation is in Java. My understanding is that you write your webapp, package it as a JAR and then simply ask Amazon to give you more power when you need it and less when you don't. Basically, it's your entire architecture as a service: you just provide the WAR file.

Comment: I've looked at Elastic Beanstalk.  However, we need more control over the environment (database, etc.) than EB provides.

Comment: I'm interested in what control you won't have, here. I haven't used EB myself, so I don't really know its capabilities but I might have some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As i read, the primary goal of the article is to Achieve LoadBalancing when there are large number of users accessing the application at a instance.  In AWS environement this can be achieved easily using Elastic Beanstalk as suggested by Christopher Schulz.

I'm not sure of what control you are looking forward for, but using Elastic Beanstalk you can control the application for  Autoscaling, Loadbalancing, Set the Max and minimum number of instances,  Email alerts when application goes down or changes to different state. Increase decrease the JVM heapspace/permgen space. Rotate tomcat logs to S3. Modify the Trigger management based on CPU utilization/network in/out etc., Switch to custom AMI for custom changes in your production environment.

Elastic Beanstalk has lot of options to have a complete control on your application. Please let me know if you have any queries regarding Beanstalk.

Comment: Our primary goal is for load balancing, as well as failover in the event a server goes down.  We have taken a quick look at Elastic Beanstalk, but wanted the flexibility that managing our own servers directly would provide instead.

Comment: For flexibility tests of the Elastic Beanstalk Loadblancing & Auto-Scaling, i used Apache Jmeter(load testing & stress testing tool) . The results were fare enough, whenever the load(no. of requests) increases, beanstalk scales the instances up and scales down when requests are reduced.